# implement decorator who will be substitute one class with another implementation

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator

What I need is something like that:

```
def method():
  my_var = module.Class1()  #actually calling Class1 constructor
  ...
```

I need to implement decorator who will be change once class definition with another, like that:

```
@substitute(module.class1 = new_module.class2)
def method():
  my_var = module.Class1()  #actually calling new_module.class2 constructor
  ...
```

Could you please give me some hints how to do that.

Comment: Are you using threads?

Comment: Could be, but I think it could be avoided. I need it for testing. To substitute classes with fake implementation, because we haven't proper dependency injection on the project

Comment: Right, so you are mocking for a test; use the `mock` library for that.

Comment: Mocking can still help with that; you can either mock the method that resolves the driver or the driver object itself. All of Python is dynamic, there are almost no limits on what you can patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called mocking. Use the [`mock` library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to do this; the library is part of Python 3.4 and up as `unittest.mock`.

With `mock` you can patch the original function *while testing only*:

```
try:
    from unittest.mock import patch
except ImportError:
    # Python < 3.4
    from mock import patch

with patch('module.class1') as class1_mock:
    mocked_instance = class1_mock.return_value
    mocked_instance.method_to_be_called.return_value = 'Test return value'

    method()

    mocked_instance.method_to_be_called.assert_called_with('Foo', 'bar')
```

The above mocks out `class1` for the duration of the `with` block, undoing the patch afterwards. The patch replaces `module.class1` with a `Mock` object, which you also have access to as `class1_mock`. The above example sets up `method_to_be_called` to return a rigged test return value, and after the test the call signature is verified.

Comment: THanks, I will take a look how it work. For this example seems the same as what I need. Buy the way, is it available in python 2.7?

Comment: @Ph0en1x: no, you'll have to install this as a testing dependency. My projects generally list these as extras in `setup.py`; `extras_require={'testing': ['coverage', 'mock', 'nose']}` for example.